# Link Server Between MS SQL Server 2008 R2 and Oracle 8.1

Tags: database, oracle, odac

I want create link server between Microsoft SQLServer 2008 R2 and Oracle , I installed  `ODAC112030_x64` and `win64_11gR2_client` and my link server setup like this code, I have an error when testing it, the error is:

```
OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "" returned message "ORA-03134" ,  Connections to this server version are no longer supported
```

How do I fix this?

```
/****** Object:  LinkedServer [LINK2]    Script Date: 06/25/2014 03:49:43 ******/
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'LINK2', @srvproduct=N'Oracle', @provider=N'OraOLEDB.Oracle', @datasrc=N'(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ip address)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID =jts)
    )
  )'
 /* For security reasons the linked server remote logins password is changed with ######## */
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'LINK2',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'username',@rmtpassword='########'

GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LINK2', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LINK2', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LINK2', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LINK2', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LINK2', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LINK2', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LINK2', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LINK2', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LINK2', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LINK2', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LINK2', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LINK2', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LINK2', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really doubt the Oracle 11gr2 client will be backward compatible to Oracle 8, especially using 64-bit drivers. Try to find an Oracle 8 or 9 client that is 32-bit, then use 32-ODBC for data connection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is not any link for download Oracle 8i or 9i in Oracle Site, do you know where can i find it? do it install in windows server 2008 R2?

Comment: You won't find those versions at the Oracle site, they are no longer supported. If you google it, you will find some sites supplying older client versions.